# Display a Wordpress shortcode with line breaks with jQuery or pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying display a wordpress shortcode with jQuery html() function.

When I put the shorcode, it shows a Google map. The shortcode is `[locations_map scope="2015-09-01,2015-09-30"]`

It displays the folowing html:

```
<div class="em-location-map-container"  style='position:relative; background: #CDCDCD; width: 100%; height: 500px;'>
    <div class='em-locations-map' id='em-locations-map-8ec52' style="width:100%; height:100%"><em>Loading Map....</em></div>
    <div class='em-locations-map-coords' id='em-locations-map-coords-8ec52' style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">{"width":"100%","height":"500px","em_ajax":true,"query":"GlobalMapData","random_id":"8ec52"}</div>
</div>
```

It display html code with line breaks

When I try to display the map with:

```
jQuery('#id-map').html('[locations_map scope="2015-07-01,2015-07-30"]');
    });
```

It shows the html code, but it has linebreaks then I get an error such as SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list due to linebreaks. How can I show the html of the shortcode in a single line?

EDIT: This is the complete code that I put in the widget

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('change', '#monthMap', function () {        
        jQuery('#id-map').html('[locations_map scope="2015-07-01,2015-07-30"]'.replace(/[\r/\n]+/g, ""));
        });
</script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="monthMap" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <select class="custom-select" id="monthMap">
            <option value="m0">- All -</option>
            <option value="m1">January</option>
            <option value="m2">February</option>
            <option value="m3">March</option>
            <option value="m4">April</option>
            <option value="m5">May</option>
            <option value="m6">Jun</option>
            <option value="m7">July</option>
            <option value="m8">August</option>
            <option value="m9">September</option>
            <option value="m10">October</option>
            <option value="m11">November</option>
            <option value="m12">December</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sakya-map">
[locations_map width="100%" height="500px"]
</div>
```

Comment: you will need to do a javascript escape... show us the wordpress code where you created the script.... may be like https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/js_escape

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
jQuery('#id-map').html('[locations_map scope="2015-07-01,2015-07-30"]'.replace(/[\r/\n]+/g, ""));
    });
```

It will replace your line breaks by empty string.

Comment: When I try your code, the shortcode is rendered in this:

Comment: @Mindastic, you can not use replace to _fix_ a syntax error in a JavaScript literal that _causes_ that syntax error. (Using a WP shortcode here means, the content is not literally `[locations_map scope="2015-07-01,2015-07-30"]`, but has been replaced with the HTML code as shown at that point already.)

Comment: @CBroe: you are right, but my answer was because the user mentions the line breaks. Now i am checking it better, i think the problem is because of the "'" ... it is printing single quotes and it seems to be breaking the string. May be the replacement can be .replace(/\'/g, "\'");

Comment: The shortcode gets replaced server-side already, so the JS code will look like this: `.html('<div…>{line break here}<div…>…')` – and that _is_ invalid JS syntax already, so you can not call replace on it.

Comment: Yes but, at that point, the code needs to be inside a variable or something. If not, it means he is writing JS code in his .php file. In that case, he has access to the PHP code and he could replace the content in PHP instead of frontend.

Comment: Yes, and that’s what the question is about. (Although it is not _that_ simple, because WP shortcodes usually produce output directly, so it is not contained inside some variable, and it would require output buffering to get it into one in the first place.)